# filtering by non-standard date string formats in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a date field in MongoDB formatted as, e.g., `"01 Aug 2020 06:26:09 GMT"`. I've created an index on this field, and my queries with filters don't throw an error, but they filter improperly — for example filtering with `db.collection.find({'date' : {'$gte' : '01 Jan 2020'}})` will still return results from before 2020. The same happens if I use `'2020-01-01'`, or `'01-01-2020'`.

Is there a way I can format by date on this field given its format?

Comment: Storing dates as string will always cause this issue, best way is to migrate your data via a script, so that you can use timestamps or date objects for filtering

Comment: You should **never** store data values as string (and then even with localized month names) , it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. MongoDB does not support months names, either you write a [$switch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) stage with 12 branches, or you use a 3rd party library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon)

Answer (score 3):

As commented by Charchit Kapoor and Wernfried Domscheit, you should avoid storing date values as Strings.

Nevertheless, for your specific case, you can convert your existing data into proper date objects **under 2 assumptions**:

1. the date format is dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
2. the timezone is always in GMT(timezone info will be ignored in following conversion script)

With proper date objects, you can perform correct filtering.

Steps:

1. `$split` the date string into tokens for processing
2. try to locate the time string by checking `$indexOfCP` with `:`. If it is a time string, `$split` into tokens and put them back into the original array
3. use an array of month with `$indexOfArray` to convert them into int values(i.e. Jan to 1, Feb to 2 ...); Meanwhile, convert other string tokens into int
4. Use `$dateFromParts` with tokens to construct proper date object
5. `$merge` back to the collection for update

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // break into tokens for processing
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tokens": {
        "$split": [
          "$date",
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // try to parse time part and break into hh, mm, ss
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tokens": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$tokens",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $ne: [
                  -1,
                  {
                    "$indexOfCP": [
                      "$$this",
                      ":"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "$split": [
                      "$$this",
                      ":"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // try to 1. parse month part and 2. convert into int
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tokens": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            tokens: "$tokens",
            monthArray: [
              "dummy",
              "Jan",
              "Feb",
              "Mar",
              "Apr",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "Aug",
              "Sep",
              "Oct",
              "Nov",
              "Dec"
            ]
          },
          in: {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$tokens",
              "as": "t",
              "in": {
                "$switch": {
                  "branches": [
                    {
                      "case": {
                        "$in": [
                          "$$t",
                          "$$monthArray"
                        ]
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "$indexOfArray": [
                          "$$monthArray",
                          "$$t"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  default: {
                    "$convert": {
                      "input": "$$t",
                      "to": "int",
                      "onError": "$$t"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "parsedDate": {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              2
            ]
          },
          "month": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              1
            ]
          },
          "day": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              0
            ]
          },
          "hour": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              3
            ]
          },
          "minute": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              4
            ]
          },
          "second": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$tokens",
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // cosmetics
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": "$parsedDate"
    }
  },
  // update back to collection
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VPUAIMlRFeF)